# Using DateDiff() in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date-arithmetic

Please consider the following query. I've realised that using `fans.checkout-fans.checkin` to calculate the difference between two dates (in days) is not a very good idea. How can I rewrite it so that I can use `DateDiff()` instead? I can't seem to simply replace `fans.checkout-fans.checkin` with this function.

```
select x.name
from (
    select fans.name,
    dense_rank() over (order by fans.checkout-fans.checkin desc) as rnk
    from fans 
    where fans.checkout-fans.checkin is not null
    ) x
where x.rnk = 1
```

Comment: You may find the [docs on datetime arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#sthref168) helpful. Not sure I inderstand what the `where` clause is doing; does that only need to be `where fans.checkout is not null`?

Comment: @AlexPoole yes you're right, it should just be `where fans.checkout is not null`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why do you believe that it is not a good idea to subtract two dates to get the number of days between them?  That's certainly the standard way to do that sort of date arithmetic in Oracle.

`DateDiff` is not a function that exists in Oracle.  I know it exists in SQL Server.  You could, of course, write your own function and call that

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dateDiff( p_dt1 IN DATE,
                                     p_dt2 IN DATE )
  RETURN NUMBER
IS
BEGIN
  RETURN p_dt1 - p_dt2;
END;
```

It's not obvious, though, what benefit you derive from doing this rather than simply continuing to subtract the two dates.

Comment: I'm working with a very a small dataset where all the dates are a few days apart and in the same month, so it is currently yielding correct results. My thinking was that if the dates were in different months/years simply subtracting the two dates wouldn't work any more. If is this not the case, then I will leave it as is and there is no need to create a function. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: @Tangler - Subtracting two dates works no matter how far apart two dates are.  Obviously, you have to consider how to interpret that data properly (i.e. just because two dates are 365 days apart does not mean that they are 1 year apart).  And humans probably prefer seeing the number of months between two dates if the range is large (`months_between`) rather than trying to figure out whether 91 days is 3 months or not trying to remember which months have 31 days.

Comment: Another disadvantage is that you're switching context from the SQL engine to the PL/SQL engine, which incurs a cost. Not noticeable for a few rows, but very noticeable over tens of thousands.

Answer (score 0):

try this one :

```
    NUMTODSINTERVAL(SYSDATE - @OLD_DT  , 'DAY')

    OR

    TRUNC (SYSDATE) - @OLD_DT
```