# DATE functions in SQL Plus don't work

Tags: sql, oracle, select, datediff

I am having issues with DATE functions in SQL Plus.  I am trying to calculate the difference in days between two dates with the following query:

```
SELECT  Item,
datebought,
datesold,
DATEDIFF('2008-06-05','2008-08-05') AS Days
FROM    auctions;
```

but I always receive the following error:  ORA-00904: "DATEDIFF": invalid identifier.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: DateDiff is a SQL server function, not oracle http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16493474/using-datediff-in-oracle

Comment: Is there any way to use it or something similar in SQL+?

Comment: The difference in days should be just Date1 - Date2.

Comment: This is very similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13466362/diff-between-dates-sql-plus

Comment: That was quite similar, not sure how I missed that one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently DATE functions do not exist within oracle.  Thus, the best option is probably to simply subtract the two dates directly.

Comment: Well, [some date functions exist](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions002.htm#i88891), just not all those from other platforms. The [date arithmetic section](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#sthref169) might be useful too.